# How to express c[i,j,k] = a[i,j] * b[i,k] in Numpy/Theano?

Tags: numpy, linear-algebra, theano

The definition

```
c[i,j,k] = a[i,j] * b[i,k] for any i, j, k
```

is an element-wise product with respect to `i`, and an outer product with respect to `j` and `k`. Is there any way to express this in NumPy/Theano without loops?

Comment: Are you looking for [`numpy.einsum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html)?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary No -- I am not even summing anything!

Comment: @MaxB: you can tell `einsum` not to sum along axes by controlling the output labels, e.g. `np.einsum('ij,ik->ijk', a, b)` would work in NumPy.

Comment: Sadly, `einsum` doesn't exist in theano ... (yet? ;))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution that works with both Numpy and Theano:

```
c = a[:, :, np.newaxis] * b[:, np.newaxis, :]
```

Comment: Yes, this is it. And works for both. Another "theano style" option, not compatible with numpy is the use of `dimshuffle`, `c = a.dimshuffle(0, 1, 'x') * b.dimshuffle(0, 'x', 1)`.